# Subtract t1 from t2 then add it to already exist t3 and display in t3 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want txtFirstNumberValue - txtSecondNumberValue and then add it already exists txtThirdNumberValue value but in my case, it is not working.

```js
function sub() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('payment_image').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_amount').value;
    var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_balance').value;
    if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
     txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
     txtSecondNumberValue = 0;
   var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);

   if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('pay_balance').value += result;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="input-box">
   <span>Amount</span>
   <input placeholder="Payment Amount" type="text" name="payment_image" onkeyup="sub();"  id="payment_image" class="number">
 </div>
 <div class="input-box">
   <span>Expences</span>
   <input placeholder="Expenses" type="text" name="expenses" id="pay_amount" onkeyup="sub();"  class="number">
 </div>
 <div class="input-box">
   <span>Balance</span>
   <input placeholder="Balance" value="15" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="pay_balance" id="pay_balance"   class="number">
 </div>
```

**txtThirdNumberValue is coming dynamically from PHP code**

Comment: What I mean is t1= 10, t2 = 5 , t3 = 15 then result = 10-5 = 5  and t3 = 15+5= 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call function `second text onblur event`

and change here

```
document.getElementById('pay_balance').value = parseInt(txtThirdNumberValue) + result;
```

```js
function sub() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('payment_image').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_amount').value;
  var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_balance').value;
  if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
    txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
  if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
    txtSecondNumberValue = 0;
  var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
  //alert(result);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('pay_balance').value = parseInt(txtThirdNumberValue) + result;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <span>Amount</span>
  <input placeholder="Payment Amount" type="text" name="payment_image" id="payment_image" class="number">
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <span>Expences</span>
  <input placeholder="Expenses" type="text" name="expenses" id="pay_amount" onblur="sub();" class="number">
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <span>Balance</span>
  <input placeholder="Balance" value="15" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="pay_balance" id="pay_balance" class="number">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert already existing value from string to number before adding result to it. Here's how to do it:

```js
function sub() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('payment_image').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_amount').value;
    var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_balance').value;
    if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
     txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
     txtSecondNumberValue = 0;
   var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);

   if (!isNaN(result)) {
    var existing = parseInt(document.getElementById('pay_balance').value);
    var newResult = result + existing;
    document.getElementById('pay_balance').value = newResult;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="input-box">
   <span>Amount</span>
   <input placeholder="Payment Amount" type="text" name="payment_image" onkeyup="sub();"  id="payment_image" class="number">
 </div>
 <div class="input-box">
   <span>Expences</span>
   <input placeholder="Expenses" type="text" name="expenses" id="pay_amount" onkeyup="sub();"  class="number">
 </div>
 <div class="input-box">
   <span>Balance</span>
   <input placeholder="Balance" value="15" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="pay_balance" id="pay_balance"   class="number">
 </div>
```

Comment: What I mean is t1= 10, t2 = 5 , t3 = 15 then result = 10-5 = 5 and t3 = 15+5= 20

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you should parseInt your 3rd value and then add it back.

Here is what you did wrong.

One more thing you should use radix value in your parseInt

```js
function sub() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('payment_image').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_amount').value;
    var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('pay_balance').value;
    if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
     txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
     txtSecondNumberValue = 0;
   var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue, 10) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue, 10);

   if (!isNaN(result)) {
    //This is what you should be doing. You didn't convert the value to int
    //You were concatinating it as a string
    var payVal = parseInt(document.getElementById('pay_balance').value, 10);
    payVal += result;
    document.getElementById('pay_balance').value = payVal;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="input-box">
   <span>Amount</span>
   <input placeholder="Payment Amount" type="text" name="payment_image" onkeyup="sub();"  id="payment_image" class="number">
 </div>
 <div class="input-box">
   <span>Expences</span>
   <input placeholder="Expenses" type="text" name="expenses" id="pay_amount" onkeyup="sub();"  class="number">
 </div>
 <div class="input-box">
   <span>Balance</span>
   <input placeholder="Balance" value="15" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="pay_balance" id="pay_balance"   class="number">
 </div>
```